# Image collection to Single Image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, image

I'm stuck with an issue in google earth engine.

I'm working with MODIS Burned Area Monthly Global 500m, for a certain polygon area:

```js
var MOD = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD64A1');
var MOD1 = MOD.filterDate('2005-06-21', '2005-09-31');
var MODlim1 = MOD.map(function(img) {return img.clip(lim)})
```

The problem is the image collection has three images (one for each month), and I need to convert this into a single image, which contains the burned area for three images in only one.
Anyone knows what function can be helpful in this situation?
I need to repeat this for every year (until 2018), so with a single image, it would be easier to analyze the data.

Comment: Are you planning to combine the data somehow? or you want just a 3 bands image?

Comment: i want the three images that compose the image collection (one for each month), converts into one image that contains the data for the three (summary: three becoming one)

Comment: Ok, but still not answering. You need one value per pixel? or 3 values per pixel? have you worked with raster images before?

Comment: one value per pixel. yes I have (ENVI, ARCGIS, QGIS, etc).. I thought I've answered your question. no need to be so condescending

Comment: Sorry, I am just trying to help. The problem here is that you have 3 values (one for each month) and you want just 1 value. Assuming that your interest is in the `burnDate` band of MCD64A1, what will be the only value for those 3 months? the latest date?

Comment: yes, each band represent the burned area per month (3 months, 3 bands). and I need the total burned area for the season. (because I need to repeat this every year so i can make the analysis) I know how to do this in other softwares, but in this case, it has to be done in engine!

Comment: Ok, let's see if I understand correctly, you need a change binary mask (burned/not burned)? In that single band image, pixels that have been burned during that period will have a value of 1, and not burned pixels a value of 0. If that is correct, how are you going to identify the date of the period? You could inset one or two metadata attributes I guess.

Answer (score 21):

```js
// UPDATE: The easiest way is now toBands().
var merged = MOD1.toBands();

// For completeness, this is the iterate() way:
var mergeBands = function(image, previous) {
  return ee.Image(previous).addBands(image);
};

var merged = MOD1.iterate(mergeBands, ee.Image([]));
```

Comment: Great! everyday you learn something new =) I didn't know that using `ee.Image([])` (an image with no bands) would make the loop start from the first image of the collection. Splitting the collection was a pain. Thanks!

Comment: Some explanation about the code would be helpful.

Comment: Learn more from the `iterate()` docs: the [user guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_iterating) and/or the [API reference](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagecollectioniterate).

Comment: I also obtained the result using: `var merged = MOD1.iterate(mergeBands, MOD1.first());`