# Remap all bands in Image

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a classification that goes from 1985 to 2020. I would like to reclassify them all to values ​​of 0 and 1, that is, vegetation and not vegetation.
I tried using the  `.remap()` function, but I must specify a band and it only works for one.

```
var asset = "projects/mapbiomas-workspace/public/collection6/mapbiomas_collection60_integration_v1";
var mapbiomas = ee.Image(asset).selfMask();

var or = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
var new = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

var mapbiomas_1985 = mapbiomas.remap({
 from: or,
 to: new,
 defaultValue: 0,
 bandName: 'classification_1985'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to map over the band names using remap function. For this purpose, use the same scheme for writting a new function

```
var asset = "projects/mapbiomas-workspace/public/collection6/mapbiomas_collection60_integration_v1";
var mapbiomas = ee.Image(asset).selfMask();

var oldvalues = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];
var newvalues = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

var bnames = mapbiomas.bandNames();

var custom_fun = function(band){
  return mapbiomas.remap({
    from: oldvalues,
    to: newvalues,
    defaultValue: 0,
    bandName: band
  }).rename([band]);
};

var vegetation = bnames.map(custom_fun);
```

This function takes the band name while mapping. Then, if you want to obtain a ee.Image with the same band names, use this useful approach from [Image collection to Single Image in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/295978/80215)

```
// from https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/295978/80215
var mergeBands = function(image, previous) {
  return ee.Image(previous).addBands(image);
};

var merged = vegetation.iterate(mergeBands, ee.Image([]));
```

I you want to obtain an ee.ImageCollection, just use `ee.ImageCollection(vegetation)` for converting the list.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. The code seems to be working, but I must be doing something wrong. When I try this command, it gives me an error `var vegetation2 = ee.ImageCollection(vegetation)  Map.addLayer(vegetation2)`. Layer 4: Tile error: Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with incompatible bands was encountered:
  First image type: 1 bands ([classification_1985]).
Current image type: 1 bands ([classification_1986]).
Some bands might require explicit casts. Also, `Map.addLayer(merged)`. return _Line 191: Cannot add an object of type <ComputedObject> to the map_.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoCarvalho yep, it's because it's an ImageColelction with multiple single-bands images. You can use `ee.ImageCollection(vegetation).toBands()` for fixing it. And for `merged`, use `ee.Image(merged)`